# Check permissions of the destination directory before installing

Tags: c++, cmake

I've been searching in the documentation and SO but I haven't found an answer for this issue.

Using [cmake](/questions/tagged/cmake), I'm trying to check the permission of the [DESTINATION](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/install.html) directory before installing some libraries.

Is there some command in cmake to do this? Do I need to make the checks with custom commands?

As an example, this is my code in my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
INSTALL( TARGETS ${LIBRARY_NAME}
 DESTINATION lib/plugins/
 PERMISSIONS OWNER_READ OWNER_WRITE OWNER_EXECUTE GROUP_READ GROUP_EXECUTE WORLD_READ WORLD_EXECUTE )
```

The idea is to check if the user has the required permissions to write in `lib/plugins/` before installing the plugins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `install(SCRIPT ...)` command flow for execute some CMake script at install stage. For example:

**check_script.cmake.in:**

```
EXECUTE_PROCESS(COMMAND test -w @CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX@/lib/plugins
    RESULT_VARIABLE res)
IF(res)
    MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "No write permissions on plugins directory")
ENDIF()
```

**CMakeLists.txt:**

```
CONFIGURE_FILE(check_script.cmake.in check_script.cmake @ONLY)
INSTALL(SCRIPT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/check_script.cmake)
INSTALL( TARGETS ${LIBRARY_NAME} DESTINATION lib/plugins/ ...)
```

As you can see, it is too many work to check file permissions on install stage. Actually, you rarely need such checks: if installing of file fails, whole installation process stops immediately, and appropriate message is shown to the user.

Comment: Any idea why I always get the message in `res` "The system cannot find the file specified" whatever file or directory I use?

Comment: Yes, `test` command is Linux-specific. Unfortunately, neither CMake commands nor [CMake command-line tool mode](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/manual/cmake.1.html#command-line-tool-mode) don't provide capability to check the directory permissions, so that check should use platform-specific commands, or use some other platform-independent interpreter (e.g. Python) which is able to perform such check.